# How to make for loop reactive in shiny server in R?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `assign` in `for loop` to create new variables that I want to use in more than one outputs in shiny ui. Following is a sample code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(fluidRow(textOutput("a")),
            fluidRow(textOutput("b")))
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  m <- reactive({1:5})

  output$a <- renderPrint({

    for (i in 1:length(m())){
      assign(paste0("h",i), "u")
      }

    list(h1,h2)
  })

  output$b <- renderPrint({

   list(h1,h2)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## Problem

Each `output` in `server` has its own environment. So, the variables `h1` to `h5` are created within `output a` and therefore not accessible by `output b`. See the result of running app:

```
[[1]] [1] "u" [[2]] [1] "u"
[[1]] function (...) tags$h1(...) <environment: namespace:htmltools> [[2]] function (...) tags$h2(...) <environment: namespace:htmltools>
```

Ideally, the second line should be same as the first line. If I move the `for loop` to `server`, there is a problem of reactivity:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

## Question

How can I make the `for loop` reactive so that all the outputs could access them?

## EDIT

I have also tried doing  following outside `output`s:

```
observe({for (i in 1:length(m())){
    assign(paste0("om",i), "u")
  }})
```

and

```
reactive({for (i in 1:length(m())){
    assign(paste0("om",i), "u")
  }})
```

Since `h1` is already a function in shiny, I changed the object name to "om". But using either of the above yields no good results:

```
output$a <- renderPrint({


    list(length(m()), om1)

  })

  output$b <- renderPrint({

   om1()
  })

Error: object 'om1' not found
Error: could not find function "om1"
```

Comment: Why not run `for loop` outside output functions then pass the assign h's in both `renderPrint()`. Just like any [function](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html) apart from shiny, processing within one is limited to function`s scope unless return is used.

Comment: @Parfait Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. Can you provide any example for my code?

Answer (score 2):

As I tried to relay in the comment, move the `for loop` outside the first `renderPrint()` function, so the h1-h5 is available for both `output$a` and `output$b`.

From your code there is no reason the loop needs to be restricted to only `output$a` as its parameter `m` is defined outside anyway:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

  mainPanel(fluidRow(textOutput("a")),
            fluidRow(textOutput("b")))
)
server <- function(input, output) {

  m <- reactive({1:5})

  for (i in 1:length(m)){
      assign(paste0("h",i), "u")
  }

  output$a <- renderPrint({

    list(h1,h2)
  })

  output$b <- renderPrint({

   list(h1,h2)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I mentioned this in my question that doing so results in problem in reactivity: `Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

Comment: See edit. Try `m` alone in `for loop`, not `m()` since `m` is not a defined function. Just ran it on my end and all h's are read in both outputs. Even tried h3 and h5.

Comment: Now, om1 prints correctly in both `output`s. But om2 to om5 do not. `Error in func() : object 'om3' not found`. I've replaced h to om since h1-h5 represent heading styles in `shiny`.